# Making 2d Array Java

Tags: multidimensional-array, combinations

say I have a 1D array like

```
int[] array1d = {1,2,3}
```

I would like to convert it into 2D `array2d[3][2]` which holding 2 int that are different. E.g.:

```
1  2
1  3
2  3
```

currently I made this

```
int[] array1d = new int[3];
        array1d[0] = 1;
        array1d[1] = 2;
        array1d[2] = 3;

int[][] array2d = new int[3][2];

for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<2; j++) {
                array2d[i][j] = array1d[j];
            }
        }
```

but it gives me only `1,2`.

Comment: Have you thought about what kind of algorithm you want to use? Also, what if your array is 1,1,2? What if it's 1,2,3,4?

Comment: the 1d arrays I use and want to covert into 2d array contain int that are different as the second one you write 1,2,3,4 and if it like that I want the output to be 1,2 1,3 1,4 2,3 2,4 3,4 I am new to this and I can't make it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, what you want is called [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) (in your example, of size 2 taken from a 3-sized array). So, order does not matter (e.g. [1, 2] equals [2, 1]).

As already specified in the comments, you should consider a more general solution and one can be found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60378/print-all-possible-combinations-of-size-r-from-an-array-of-size-n). Besides the actual code, you will also find a code reviews from Codereview community.

Answer (score 0):

i have done this using random numbers.try this code

`    import java.util.Random;

```
     public final class RandomInteger {

   public static void main(String... aArgs){

    Random randomGenerator = new Random();  
    int[] array1d = new int[3];
    array1d[0] = 1;
    array1d[1] = 2;
    array1d[2] = 3;
    int[] array2d = new int[3][2];
    int randomInt;
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
          for (int j=0; j<2; j++) {
              randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(3);
              array2d[i][j] = array1d[randomInt];
                                   }
                            }

                                              }
                                    }
```

`